# Getting error when executing the stored procedure using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

when executing a stored procedure. I need to copy data from the database I am building to the live database. The code inserted the data into `TestTextmessage` table and updateed `TextMessage` table. The error occurred when try to insert into the `TestMobileRecipient` table that is the reason why the table is empty.

The table structure and code are below

[image: Table Structure]

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSendITMessage]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i int
    DECLARE @idmessage int
    DECLARE @numrows int

    DECLARE @messagehold TABLE 
                         (
                             idx SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
                             MessageId INT
                         )
    DECLARE @InsertedID INT

    INSERT INTO @messagehold
        SELECT DISTINCT Id 
        FROM [MPFT_SendIT].dbo.TextMessage 
        WHERE DontSendBefore < GETDATE()  
          AND DateSent IS NULL
          AND MessageSent = 0 

     SET @i = 1
     SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @messagehold)

     IF @numrows > 0
         WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @messagehold))
         BEGIN
             SET @idmessage = (SELECT MessageId FROM @messagehold WHERE idx = @i)

             --Do something with Id here
             PRINT @idmessage

             INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTextMessage] ([Origin], [MessageBody], [MessageSent], [DateCreated], DontSendBefore)
                 SELECT 
                     'LogIT', MessageBody, 0, GETDATE(), DontSendBefore
                 FROM 
                     [MPFT_SendIT].dbo.TextMessage
                 WHERE Id = @idmessage

            SET @InsertedID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY();        

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestMobileRecipient] ([MessageId], MobileNumber])
            VALUES (@InsertedID, (SELECT MobileNumber FROM MobileRecipient
                                  WHERE MessageId = @idmessage))

            UPDATE TextMessage 
            SET DateSent = GETDATE(),
                MessageSent = 1
            WHERE Id = @idmessage

            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    END
```

Comment: SQL Server uses **T-SQL** (Transact-SQL) as its programming language - **PL/SQL** is the Oracle equivalent - so what are you really using?? SQL Server + T-SQL, or Oracle + PL/SQL ?? Please fix your conflicting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message is very clear. Your sub-query `SELECT MobileNumber FROM MobileRecipient WHERE MessageId= @idmessage` is returning more than 1 row

Change the insertion of table TestMobileRecipient to following

```
Insert into [dbo].[TestMobileRecipient]
(
     [MessageId]
    ,[MobileNumber]
)
SELECT @InsertedID
     , MobileNumber 
FROM   MobileRecipient
WHERE  MessageId= @idmessage
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your this line

```
 SET @idmessage = (SELECT MessageId FROM @messagehold WHERE idx = @i)
```

with

```
 SET @idmessage = (SELECT top 1 MessageId FROM @messagehold WHERE idx = @i)
```